# Certificate Enrollment fails after working all morning

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, ad-certificate-services

Good morning, everyone. I was working on SSL cert tasks all yesterday morning without issue, and then all of the sudden I get a failure when making a new request and it looks like this:

[image: Failure Message]

What is even more strange is that instead of the request showing up in my Personal>Certifiates folder, it goes straight to the "Issued Certificates" folder under my CA (as if it was issued without error). Normally I would go to my CA, click on "Submit New Request" and then browse to the request after exporting it from "Personal>Certificates".

I really have no idea what is going on or why it started to do this out of nowhere. I have already tried restarting the server but to no avail.

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: What do the event logs say? What steps did you take to get to this step?

Comment: Zapto - To get to this step I did what I would normally do: Right-click, request new certificate, select AD Enrollment Policy, select the correct template, configure settings, enter C, S, L, O, OU, put the FQDN in CN and DNS fields, click Apply, OK, Enroll. 

I get this error message after clicking Enroll, when normally it would complete without issue and was doing so for most of yesterday morning until this randomly popped up.

The event logs show the exact same error with no further details to dive into.